# NodeJS how to check if an object has all the propertie values same as in another object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have two objects one is constructed by reading a JSON file and another is constructed from query passed in as url parameter similar to as follows:

```
q = req.query.query
```

which really has subset of JSON data. For example the JSON data parsed through JSON.parse() may have a list as follows:

boxofficehits.json

```
[
    {
        "id": "Strawberry swing",
        "artist": "Coldplay",
        "release": "19 Jun, 2009",
        "other entries": ""
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "No sleep",
        "artist": "Wiz Khalifa",
        "release": "20 April, 2011",
        "other entries": ""
        ...
    }    


]
```

My query object may look like follows:
    var q = {"id": ""Strawberry swing"};

I am reading the JSON file through require.

```
var boxofficehits = require('./boxofficehits.json');
```

I want  to return an object that will look like the following:

```
    {
        "id": "Strawberry swing",
        "artist": "Coldplay",
        "release": "19 Jun, 2009",
        "other entries": ""
        ...
    }
```

Other than the obvious way of looping and checking through properties, is there a way/library that I can use for accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for a library to do something are considered off-topic here at StackOverflow.  Questions asking how to implement something yourself that show your first try at it are on-topic.  Javascript does not have an object compare function built in that would tell you if two separate objects have all the same properties.  The only way to determine that is to loop through the properties and see if both have the same properties and values.

Answer (score 1):

Check out congruence ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/congruence). It does exactly what you're looking for:

```
var template = {
  id: 57,
  name: 'Travis'
};
var object = {
  id: 57,
  name: 'Travis',
  color: 'blue',
  foo: 1
};

// the extra object properties are ignored 
assert.isTrue(_.similar(template, object));
```

You can also setup templates:

```
var object = {
  a: 3.1415926535,
  foo: {
    bar: {
      b: 'hello world',
      c: [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ],
      d: new Date()
    }
  }
};
var matchingTemplate = {
  a: 3.1415926535,
  foo: _.congruent({
    bar: _.congruent({
      b: _.isString,
      c: _.isArray,
      d: _.compose(_.not, _.isFunction)
    })
  })
};

assert.isTrue(_.congruent(matchingTemplate, object));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Loadsh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) library provides [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) method. The code below works:

```
var boxofficehits = require('./boxofficehits.json');

var match={
            "id": "Strawberry swing",
            "artist": "Coldplay"
    };
var result = _.filter(boxofficehits , match);
```

result:

```
{
        "id": "Strawberry swing",
        "artist": "Coldplay",
        "release": "19 Jun, 2009",
        "other entries": ""
        ...
    }
```